# Declaring TextView Error

Tags: android, textview

```
final TextView nt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.notify);
```

It says that this returns null, but indead it is in the R.java and the main and has text with it. I have no idea what is wrong, any help?

Error:

```
""=(No explicit return value)
```

Public void that uses NT:

```
public void addNotification() {

 if (nt.getText()==("yes")) {

        NotificationManager notifier = (NotificationManager)this.
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int icon = R.drawable.icon4;
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Easy Settings Has Started", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent toLaunch = new Intent(this, EasySettings.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, toLaunch, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Easy Settings", "Click to quickly access Easy Settings.", contentIntent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;
        notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notifier.notify(0x007, notification);

        } else {

            if (nt.getText()==("no")) {

                //do nothing

            }

        }
}
```

OnCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView nt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.notify);

    try {
        checkSB();
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    checkRing();
    checkWifi();
    checkBt();

    AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
    re.setTesting(false);
    adview.loadAd(re);
}
```

Comment: findViewById looks for the view as it is declared in the onCreate() method with setContentView(). Are you sure you did that right? Maybe a little more code could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setContentView()` in your `onCreate()` method before using `findViewById()`.  Here is an example of doing this...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set this to whatever your layout is
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Now you can call the activity's findViewById() method...
    TextView nt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.notify);
}
```

**Edit**
Your `nt` variable is not in the same scope as your `addNotification()` method.  Fix this by making it a class member or passing it into your `addNotification()` method.

Also, to compare strings you should really be using `.equals()` not `==`.  `==` checks to see if it is the same object whereas `.equals()` will match the text between two strings.

**Edit (again)**

I'm going to assume you already have `nt` at the class level there's no way this would compile if not.  Judging by what you've said, it seems your problem stems from the fact that you're creating a separate `nt` variable in your `onCreate()`.  Change your code to something like the following (I've stripped out the unimportant parts).

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView nt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Do not create a new instance, use the one you have...
        nt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.notify);

        // Do whatever you were doing...
    }

    public void addNotification() {
        // This *should* work...
        if (nt.getText().equals("yes")) {
            // Do whatever you were doing...
        }
        else if (nt.getText().equals("no")) {
            // Do nothing...
        }
    }
}
```

If this doesn't get you started then I'm not sure what the issue is.  If this does not fix your problem you should post what you get from your `logcat`.

Comment: I have a public void outside of the OnCreate method...that uses nt.

Comment: Edit your question and post some code showing exactly what you're trying to do...

Comment: Edited by answer to reflect what you've just posted.

Comment: Can you please teamview with me I need help!
ID - 624 264 021
PASS - 7783

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have declared a field declared `TextView nt`.

In your `onCreate` method, you create another (local) variable nt, storing the TextView in this local variable, not in the global field.

Change this:

```
final TextView nt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.notify);
```

into this:

```
nt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notify);
```

Comment: yes but for the third time i need the nt textview for a public void outside of the OnCreate Method

Comment: As onCreate() should normally always be called before any other methods, it should still work. Please, give more code. Help us to help you.

Comment: Why not? What happened? You dó have the globally declared field 'TextView nt;' ?

Comment: Can you please teamview with me I need help! ID - 624 264 021 PASS - 7783

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `findViewById()` after you called `setContentView()`.

Comment: If so where can I place it? Because when I place it beneath it the void can not read the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `nt` variable outside the `onCreate()` method. You're declaring it as a local variable, so no other method will be able to see it.

```
TextView nt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    nt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.notify);

    try {
        checkSB();
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    checkRing();
    checkWifi();
    checkBt();

    AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
    re.setTesting(false);
    adview.loadAd(re);
}
```

Comment: That works, but for some odd reason it still gives me a stupid error ill update on the error code after i debug

Comment: Can you please teamview with me I need help! ID - 624 264 021 PASS - 7783

Answer (score 0):

Look if your textview is in your main layout and not in another . And can you put some log please ?